# Results different documents for the same query

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('rien').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "id": "10356"
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              "sys_date": {
                "$gte": newDate(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000)
              }
            },
            {
              "war_date": {
                "$gte": newDate(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000)
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$b_id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      ads: {
        $addToSet: {
          "s": "$s",
          "ca": "$ca"
        }
      },
      files: {
        $addToSet: {
          "system": "$system",
          "hostname": "$hostname"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "ads.s": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$b_id",
      total_count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "total_count": 1,
      results: {
        $slice: [
          "$data",
          0,
          50
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

When I execute this pipelines 5 times, it results in different set of documents. It is 3 node cluster. No sharding enabled. Have 10million documents. Data is static.

Any ideas about the inconsistent results? I feel I am missing some fundamentals here.

Comment: because you are soring using array field `"ads.s": -1:`, you can sort before `$group` stage using `"s": -1`.

Comment: second thing, I workaround your query [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fPpug3RK-Ex), don't trust on `$addToSet` operator this will change the order of set.

Comment: I will check these two. Thanks @turivishal. How does that addToSet change order?

Comment: AddToSet is is a Set which is an unordered list. I will change the order. But push doesn't change the order

Comment: Thanks @varman, push doesn't remove duplicates in this case. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes @Gibbs , push doesn't remove duplicates, If we need to remove duplicates, first `addtoset`, then `$unwind`, then `sort` then `push`

Comment: I will try this and check the performance, let you know. Thanks Varman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems,

1. `"ads.s": -1` will not work because, its an array field `$sort` will not apply in array field
2. `$addToSet` will not maintain sort order even its ordered from previous stage,

   - here mentioned in [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) documentation => *Order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.*
   - and also here mentioned in [accumulators-group-addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#accumulators-group) => *Order of the array elements is undefined*
   - and also a JIRA ticket [SERVER-8512](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8512) and [DOCS-1114](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1114)

---

You can use [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) operator for ascending order and `$reduce` for descending order result from `$setUnion`,

I workaround I am adding a solution below, I am not sure this is good option or not but you can use if this not affect performance of your query,

I am adding updated stages here only,

- remain same

```
  { $match: {} }, // skipped
  { $group: {} }, // skipped
```

- `$sort`, optional its up to your requirement if you want order by main document

```
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
```

- `$setUnion`, treating arrays as sets. If an array contains duplicate entries, $setUnion ignores the duplicate entries, and second its return array in ascending order on the base of first field that we specified in `$group` stage is `s`, but make sure all element in array have `s` as first field,
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of array and concat arrays current element `$$this` and initial value `$$value`, this will change order of array in descending order,

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      ads: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $setUnion: "$ads" },
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: [["$$this"], "$$value"] }
        }
      },
      files: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $setUnion: "$files" },
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: [["$$this"], "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- remain same

```
  { $group: {} }, // skipped
  { $project: {} } // skipped
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R04ZTdiizRv)

---

> `$setUnion` mentioned in documentation: *The order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.*, but I have tested every way its returning in ascending order perfectly, why I don't know,
>
> I have asked question in MongoDB Developer Forum [does-setunion-expression-operator-order-array-elements-in-ascending-order?](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/does-setunion-expression-operator-order-array-elements-in-ascending-order/12065), they replied => it will not guarantee of order!

Comment: I had that second group on the same field to get unique counts. How to add that also?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I ll check each point.

Comment: Ya there is a problem in second $group, group by `$b_id` but its not present in previous stage. so by default it will group all documents in single, is that you real want or missed?

Comment: I squeezed the query, it has b_id in previous pipeline' output. But as you said, severity is part of an array

Comment: Okay have you checked the playground in answer? i have sorted `ads` in `$addFields`, stage, that is the only sorting part i have solved  using that extra stage, so you don't need to $unwind, $group, and $sort part again for sorting, and other your things will be remain same.

Comment: Yes, I  checked that, it looks like it will suit my use case. I will try soon and approve it. Thanks +1

Comment: Bro, I have few doubts here. 1. `$addToSet` doesn't preserve order but in this case it applies to the document which is inside a grouped document - correct? 2. Array sort - If array always contains one element, will this work? It does seem work. 3. Now, I suspect the reason for this problem - `ads.s` has only values from 1-10. I have 10m documents. In this case all docs' `ads.s` falls under one of `1-10`. Does this cause sort issue? If I add, another unique field to decide the order, it does seem work, I tried adding `_id` in sort.

Comment: 1) yes, 2) yes, so there is no matter of order if it has only one document. if you are sure then it is ok to use `$addToSet`, 3) If I add, another unique field to decide the order, it does seem work, I tried adding _id in sort., 4) i am not getting but if your mean to say `{ "ads._id": -1 }` will work? no, this will not work, because `$addToSet` if main problem. ,, is my approach working properly? or are you getting any problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding two sort orders. One with ads.s and another with _id. It kinda works. Because I see the problem with overall documents. Not with addToSet docs.

Comment: Okay got it, it is for main document order. yes that is correct, but are getting ads array to sorted?

Comment: No, that array need not to be in sorted order for my case.

Comment: Okay because of this `{ "ads.s": -1 }`, we thought you need this array to be sorted as well, anyway i am glad you have resolved your problem.

Comment: To confirm again, that does the top level doc sort, not the addToSet one. Correct? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: right that `{ "ads.s": -1 }` does top level sort not that array elements,